# Node.js type error first argument must be a string or buffer

Tags: node.js

I have written a small code in node.js to insert a document in MongoDB collection. But as I make a request for profile route I get the error I mentioned in the title. I can't figure out which line is causing the problem, maybe it is the one after insertOne method. The code is:

```
http
  .createServer((req, res) => {

    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    var url = req.url;

    if (url == "/") {
      res.end("<h1>Basic route</h1>");
    } else if (url == "/profile") {

      mydb
        .collection("record")
        .insertOne({ username: "vipul", password: "vipul1234" }, (err, result) => {
          if (err) res.end(err);
          else res.end("inserted successfully");
        });
    } else if (url == "/about") {
      res.end("<h1>About Us Page</h1>");
    } else {
      let date = Date();
      res.end("<h1>Incorrect URL</h1><h2>", date, "</h2>");
    }
  })
  .listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server listening at port 3000");
  });
```

Please guide me through. I am a beginner to Node!

Comment: `res.end` doesn't take objects. so `res.end(err);` might fail. Try `res.end(err.message);`

Comment: Also don't think that [`res.end()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback) will accept comma-delimited parameters...

Comment: Can you share your mongodb config file?

Comment: I've made some changes and now it is working!!

Answer (score 1):

About this:

```
if (err)
    res.end(err);
else
    res.end("inserted successfully");
```

`res.end` does not accept the error itself. You have to pass it a string or a buffer.

<sub>(See more here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback)</sub>

You can try this:

```
if (err)
    res.end(err.message);
else
    res.end("inserted successfully");
```

Comment: I have corrected that and it has worked but now it is giving MongoError there are no users authenticated